# Heading changes font and position when not in full screen

Tags: html, css

I am making a website using HTML and CSS and the heading displays fine in full screen but when I make it half the screen size the header (h1) changes to the default font and aligns to the left instead of the center as it should.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Home page</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="css/filesheet1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home page</a></li>
<li><a href="about us.html">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="our songs.html">Our songs</a></li>
<li><a href="see us play.html">See us play</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
<li><a href="playing a concert.html">Playing a concert</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1>Home</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code (sorry if there's a lot as I have no idea whats causing this issue I have put it all there):

```
    /* set sizing to border box method */
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: inherit;
}
/* set maximum and minimum widths for the body and centre within the viewport */
body {
text-align: center;
border: solid;
border-radius: 15px;
border-color: #CACFD2;
box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #888888;
background-color: #CACFD2;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 1024px;
min-width: 256px;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 24px;
padding-left: 24px;
padding-right: 24px;
}
html, html body{
height: 100%;
}
html{
background-color: white;
}
/* header */
header{
}
header p {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 0px;
}
header h1 {
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
}
/* the menu */
nav ul {
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: none;
border: none;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 16px;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline;
border-right: 2px solid #111111;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #111111;
}
nav li.selected{
color: #606060;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
font-weight: 900;
}
/* biographies */
section {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 24px;
min-height: 320px;
padding-left: 24px;
padding-right: 24px;
}
/* the aside */
aside {
}
/* footer */
footer {
}
footer p.copyright {
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
}
footer p.contact {
text-align: right;
}

/* small images are set to 200px in height */
img.small {
float: left;
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 24px;
margin-right: 24px;
}
/* medium images can be 50% of the container elementâ€™s width, up to 360px */
img.medium {
max-width: 360x;
width: 50%;
}
/* large images are 100% of the container elementâ€™s width */
img.large {
width: 100%;
}
/* add the same style of border to the elements which are to have borders */
section, img {
border: 2px solid #B1B1B1;
border-radius: 16px;
}
/* the bits that are specific to a wide viewport (over 56em) */
@media{
min-width: 900px
}
article {
float: left;
width: 66%;
}
aside {
float: left;
padding-left: 24px;
width: 34%;
}
footer {
clear: both;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/* Styles go here */

/* set sizing to border box method */
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: inherit;
}
/* set maximum and minimum widths for the body and centre within the viewport */
body {
text-align: center;
border: solid;
border-radius: 15px;
border-color: #CACFD2;
box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 #888888;
background-color: #CACFD2;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 1024px;
min-width: 256px;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 24px;
padding-left: 24px;
padding-right: 24px;
}
html, html body{
height: 100%;
}
html{
background-color: white;
}
/* header */
header{
}
header p {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 0px;
}
header h1 {
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
}
/* the menu */
nav ul {
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: none;
border: none;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 16px;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline;
border-right: 2px solid #111111;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #111111;
}
nav li.selected{
color: #606060;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
font-weight: 900;
}
/* biographies */
section {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 24px;
min-height: 320px;
padding-left: 24px;
padding-right: 24px;
}
/* the aside */
aside {
}
/* footer */
footer {
}
footer p.copyright {
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
}
footer p.contact {
text-align: right;
}

/* small images are set to 200px in height */
img.small {
float: left;
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 24px;
margin-right: 24px;
}
/* medium images can be 50% of the container elementâ€™s width, up to 360px */
img.medium {
max-width: 360px;
width: 50%;
}
/* large images are 100% of the container elementâ€™s width */
img.large {
width: 100%;
}
/* add the same style of border to the elements which are to have borders */
section, img {
border: 2px solid #B1B1B1;
border-radius: 16px;
}
/* the bits that are specific to a wide viewport (over 56em) */
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {

}
article {
float: left;
width: 66%;
}
aside {
float: left;
padding-left: 24px;
width: 34%;
}
footer {
clear: both;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Home page</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home page</a></li>
<li><a href="about us.html">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="our songs.html">Our songs</a></li>
<li><a href="see us play.html">See us play</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
<li><a href="playing a concert.html">Playing a concert</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1>Home</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This should work for you now.

Comment: what do you mean by normal css above?

Comment: just simply take that `h1{
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}` out of the @media and put it above it

Comment: it's not in @ media it's by itself at the bottom

Comment: oh then I think you are missing a `}` to close your media query

Comment: could you edit the code above so that I would be able to see what you have? Thanks

Comment: are you using the media query for anything at all? Just curious because as you have it right now its not properly formated. I got it working. I'll post the working solution in my answer above

Comment: it doesn't i am afraid

Comment: hmm I'm not sure then. I know in your css above the media query you have is incorrect. You have `@media{
min-width: 900px
}` but it should be `@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {}`

Comment: still not working, if i delete all of the media bit it still won;t work so maybe the problems elsewhere

Comment: is any of your styling working? cause the other thing I would check is to make sure that the css file is included in the html correctly

Comment: i am so sorry just realized i was editing the wrong style sheet it works 100% fine, thanks so much for you help